# How to get Hindi (Unicode) Text From Textbox?

Tags: c#

I have created one desktop application with 1 textbox and one button and set textbox font property to "Krutidev" ,while typing in textbox it showed value in hindi but while inserting that value in sql server it showed in English,
I want textbox value in Hindi while storing.
back end code

```
 string Text = txtname.Text;
        string sql = "insert into m_Language(fullname) values(@HindiText)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HindiText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = val;
        int res;
        res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        res = 1;
        con.Close();
```

Comment: How did it show it in English? Can you add an example in your post?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose if i type ना in hindi it appear as it is but at backend code if you see that textbox value it showed "na".

Comment: @PraveenPaulose my sample codebehind is 
 string Text = txtname.Text;
        string sql = "insert into m_Language(fullname) values(@HindiText)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HindiText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = val;
        int res;
        res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        res = 1;
        con.Close();

Comment: Add your code to the post.

Comment: What is val? You are taking the textbox value in `Text`

Comment: @PraveenPaulose  yes i mistakenly write val instead of Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a font 'Krutidev' which interprets Latin alphabets and displays it in Hindi. In effect the text underneath is still **na** as per your example. It is the font which is displaying na as the Hindi script. This is why you see plain text in your database.

If you want to achieve saving Hindi Text, you should use the Hindi soft Keyboard of your computer, which will punch Unicode characters into your text box and these Unicode characters will then be seen as Hindi in your database too.

You can enable Hindi on Windows 8 as shown below

[image]

Once you have enabled Hindi, in your system tray select the Hindi Language and start typing.

[image]

Comment: without any Hindi soft keyboard is it possible? or else is their any hindi font need to be install other than KrutiDev

Comment: It is not the font. The font still uses the Latin characters underneath just like Webdings which prints images which by just changing the font will just show normal English. I have added a link to set your current keyboard to Hindi. There is no other way to achieve this.

Comment: Facing same problem after enabling Hindi keyboard

Comment: @user3260058 After enabling the Hindi keyboard, can you open and type in Notepad and tell me what you see

Comment: i followed your link step but i am using windows 8 so i got following options
1. Region: inside there is three tabs
    a.Format
    b.location
    c.Administrative
in format tab i set format to Hindi

Comment: After following the steps do you get Hindi characters when typing in Notepad?

Comment: @user3260058 I have added images to the answer to help set Hindi as your Language.

Comment: Now i am able to write in hindi but need to check with code

Comment: @user3260058 All you need to do now, is type into your texbox on the Form with the Hindi keyboard and save the data. Your database should have Hindi text then.

Comment: Praveen Paulose Thank You very much i got needed output.

Comment: I am new user i am trying to vote but it give message you need 15 reputation

Comment: @user3260058 The link shows you how to mark it as an answer. You do not need 15 reputations to mark it as an answer. It helps others with similar problems know that this answer solved the problem.