# How to force a certain culture on a string c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I’m working on localizing hard coded string messages in a solution that has more than 30 projects.
All the user messages should be localized ,except for the Log messages, as those will be read by US developers so they have to stay in US English language.In all solution projects, a string with the same message had been created in every file (with different variable name in each) which goes into the User and Log messages as well.

```
String s = "Unable to populate list: "
Log.Warning(LogCategory.NameLookupDialog, s + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
TXMessageBox.Show(s);
```

The string in the TXMessageBox will be pulled out of the resources files,but the one that goes into the Log message should stay US English.

Is there a way to force the US English culture on the s string when it goes into the Log message ?On other words , if the culture of the application changed for example to Indian , the Log message should stay with the US English.
Here is what I have tried so far :
I changed the culture of the application to Indian , then I tried to set the culture of a label text only to US English ,but it didn’t work :

```
public void SwitchCulture()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            this.lblLogMessage.Text = string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), this.lblLogMessage.Text);
        }
```

When I run this I still see all the labels in Indian .
So any ideas how to force the culture on the string ?

Comment: You aren't doing any culture-specific conversions there.

Comment: Strings aren't localized, strings are strings. *Resources* can be localized, but that's another matter altogether. If you don't have a question on how to retrieve localized resources, then that's probably what you're after. Then, if you want certain strings to not be localized, that's easy enough: don't get them from localized resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString("ResourceKey", new CultureInfo("en-US"))

where AppResources is the file name and class name of the resources and ResourceKey is the resource key name inside in resx file.

Comment: Works now ! Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the font you are using on your label won't accept Latin characters.  See this previous answer: [How to get Hindi (Unicode) Text From Textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904465/how-to-get-hindi-unicode-text-from-textbox)

If that doesn't work, try setting the CultureInfo on the current thread to EN-US *before* you set the label's text. Then set it back to Hindi when you're done.